# Can you pass keyword arguments instead of positional arguments to argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

Suppose you have a python function, as so:

```
def foo(spam, eggs, ham):
    pass
```

You could call it using the positional arguments only (`foo(1, 2, 3)`), but you could also be explicit and say `foo(spam=1, eggs=2, ham=3)`, or mix the two (`foo(1, 2, ham=3)`).

Is it possible to get the same kind of functionality with argparse? I have a couple of positional arguments with keywords, and I don't want to define all of them when using just one.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo',nargs='?',default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('--foo',dest='foo',default=None)

parser.add_argument('bar',nargs='?',default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('--bar',dest='bar',default=None)

parser.add_argument('baz',nargs='?',default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('--baz',dest='baz',default=None)

print parser.parse_args()
```

which works mostly as you describe:

```
temp $ python test.py 1 2 --baz=3
Namespace(bar='2', baz='3', foo='1')
temp $ python test.py --baz=3
Namespace(bar=None, baz='3', foo=None)
temp $ python test.py --foo=2 --baz=3
Namespace(bar=None, baz='3', foo='2')
temp $ python test.py 1 2 3
Namespace(bar='2', baz='3', foo='1')
```

python would give you an error for the next one in the function call analogy, but argparse will allow it:

```
temp $ python test.py 1 2 3 --foo=27.5
Namespace(bar='2', baz='3', foo='27.5')
```

You could probably work around that by using [mutually exclusive groupings](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion)

Comment: If the arguments have defaults, will I be able to do `test.py --baz=3`?

Comment: @Glycan -- You can hack around that with judicious use of `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` and setting the default explicitly.  See my update.

Comment: Oh, that sucks, that's the behaviour I was looking for. I dislike hacks that don't make sense.

Comment: @Glycan -- What behavior are you looking for?  The one where you raise an error if foo is specified twice?

Comment: If you're going to use `--help`, you may want to set `help=argparse.SUPPRESS` on one of the `add_argument`s if you don't want options to appear twice.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that using `argparse.SUPPRESS` doesn't work with `type=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this module: [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for [Argparse defaults](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#default)